# pgcli won't run, is giving me an odd error

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl

This should have a `pgcli` tag, but I don't have enough reputation to create that...

Anyway, I recently did a `brew upgrade`, and now pgcli won't run for me.  I'm literally up-arrowing to get the command, so I know it's the command that worked before.  It's below (though, when I run it, I'm using literals, not the environment variables).

```
$ pgcli --single-connection "host=$HOST_NAME dbname=$DB_NAME user=$DB_USERNAME sslcert=$DB_CRT sslkey=$DB_KEY sslrootcert=$DB_TRUST_STORE sslmode=$DB_SSL_MODE"  
invalid connection option "dsn"
```

I've tried this w/o the "--single-connection", no change.  I replaced "pgcli" with "psql" and it worked, but then I don't have pgcli.

I've [googled this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=pgcli+%22invalid+connection+option%22+dsn) and come up empty.  I replaced my config file with the [current sample config](https://www.pgcli.com/config), none of that changes anything.

The relevant log lines are below.  Note that I have executed `pip install keyring` before this.

```
2022-10-04 10:51:35,886 (39248/MainThread) pgcli.main INFO - Default pager found in PAGER environment variable: "less"
2022-10-04 10:51:35,886 (39248/MainThread) pgcli.main WARNING - import keyring failed: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'keyring'").
2022-10-04 10:51:35,888 (39248/MainThread) pgcli.main ERROR - traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/conninfo.py", line 96, in _parse_conninfo\n    return pq.Conninfo.parse(conninfo.encode())\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/pq/pq_ctypes.py", line 905, in parse\n    raise exc\npsycopg.OperationalError: invalid connection option "dsn"\n\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgcli/main.py", line 627, in connect\n    pgexecute = PGExecute(database, user, passwd, host, port, dsn, **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgcli/pgexecute.py", line 161, in __init__\n    self.connect(database, user, password, host, port, dsn, **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgcli/pgexecute.py", line 206, in connect\n    conn_info = make_conninfo(**conn_params)\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/conninfo.py", line 59, in make_conninfo\n    _parse_conninfo(conninfo)\n  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgcli/3.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/conninfo.py", line 98, in _parse_conninfo\n    raise e.ProgrammingError(str(ex))\npsycopg.ProgrammingError: invalid connection option "dsn"\n\n'
```

I tried formatting my connection string as a URL as below, but that gives me an error that makes me think that pgcli is truncating the URL and not actually connecting the way I'm asking it to.

```
$ pgcli "postgresql://$HOST_NAME/$DB_NAME&user=$DB_USERNAME&sslcert=$DB_CRT&sslkey=$DB_KEY&sslrootcert=$DB_TRUST_STORE&sslmode=$DB_SSL_MODE&ssl=true"
connection failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "$DB_IP", user "$NON_DB_USER_NAME", database "$DB_NAME&user=$DB_USERNAME&ssl=true&sslcert=$ROUGHLY_HALF_OF_THE_SSL_CRT_PATH", SSL on
connection to server at "$HOST_NAME" ($DB_IP), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "$CLIENT_IP", user "$NON_DB_USER_NAME", database "$DB_NAME&user=$DB_USERNAME&ssl=true&sslcert=$ROUGHLY_HALF_OF_THE_SSL_CRT_PATH", SSL off
```

Does anyone know what to do?  Where to look?  I've read [the FAQ](https://www.pgcli.com/faq), I've googled, I've looked in the error log...  I don't know what to try next.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but 1) the problem may be related to a mismatch (and too big differences) between pgcli version and the server version and 2) did you try  `psql` which is the default standard client? At least if you can connect with it you have a path forward and can work better to understand what is specifically wrong with `pgcli`.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is offtopic, I searched, there are other pgcli questions on SO.  Where should it live?

Comment: > did you try psql which is the default standard client?

Yes, as I say above:

> I replaced "pgcli" with "psql" and it worked, but then I don't have pgcli.